# What site should this question go on?

Tags: discussion, closed-questions, close-reasons

Here is a link to the question (on Arqade) - [link](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/407649/valorant-on-steam)

Here is a link to the question (on GameDev SE - [link](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/210436/valorant-on-steam)

---

Here is the question:

> Has Riot Games ever said anything about putting VALORANT on Steam?
> Have there ever been any rumours about doing so? If so, when was this,
> and what was said?
>
> I know VALORANT is available on Windows, which is what I play it on,
> but it's not on other OSs (to my knowledge).
>
> Recently, I think, there were some rumours about putting VALORANT on
> Linux (pretty sure there's a YouTube video about it)... I'm not sure
> how true that it, considering Linux is much less popular than other
> OSs (at least, I think it is).
>
> ---
>
> Also, have they ever said anything about why it's not on Steam, considering they would be able to greatly expand their playerbase if it was?

That question was originally on the Arqade SE. It was then closed - the reason why being that it was off-topic, and should be moved to the GameDev SE.

Here is the close reason:

> Questions about Game Design and Development are off topic. This
> includes speculative questions about developer intent, with respect to
> both mechanics and narrative. You might want to ask over at GameDev.SE, but be sure to read their FAQ.

So I moved it. For roughly a day, it was on the GameDev SE. It was then closed - the reason why being that it was off-topic and should be moved to the Arqade SE. Sounds familiar? It does to me too.

So I moved it again. And it was closed again. For the same reason, and with the same suggestion.

---

So what site should it be on?

---

Here is a link to the same question on Arqade Meta, if you want it - [link](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17068/what-site-should-this-question-be-on)

Comment: Note the portion you removed from the close reason: "You might want to ask over at GameDev.SE, **but be sure to read their FAQ**".

Comment: "should be moved to the Arqade SE" is also not present in the close reason or any comments left on the question you asked on GameDev.StackExchange. You may have extrapolated that from the experience on Arqade, but it's not something you were told here.